# Run function when animation completed without setTimeout - Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, animation, callback

So I made an animation where a `div` called "slider" appears from the left side of the screen, expands to the right and then disappears on the right side of the screen. What I have done is start with `width: 0;` then transform to the full width, change `position` to `right` and have the `width` go back to 0 and change `display` to `none`. The animation works fine, but probably with excessive use of the `setTimeout`. Is there a better way to write this piece of JavaScript and have one animation start when the previous has finished without the use of `setTimout`?

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  slider.style.width = "60%";
  slider.style.position = "absolute";
  setTimeout(function(){
    slider.style.right = "25%";
    slider.style.width = "0px";}, 750);
  setTimeout(function(){
    slider.style.display = "none";}, 1500);
});
```

Comment: what you did can be achieved with CSS transitions.

Comment: Thank you, only that doesn't accomplish what I had in mind. What I was hoping to learn, is if there is a way I can do this without hard-coding the delays, but have each action or actions be exicuted the moment the precious has finished.